# How to theme the header bar close button in GTK+3?

Tags: gtk, themes, gtk3

I'd like to change the style of the close button on GTK+3 windows with so called "header bars", where the window is rendered without decoration and GTK composes title bar and widgets.

What kind of element is the "X" close button, and what CSS classes does it belong to (if any)?

[image: Screenshot]

Note that this is *not* part of  the window manager theme but actually drawn by GTK+.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a GtkButton with icon `window-close-symbolic` with style class `titlebutton` (the same class as the other buttons on the header), assuming the app is using the built-in close button.

Comment: `.titlebutton` it is!

Comment: @jku: is there any documentation on the style classes that may be used, or do you have to resort to reading a widget's source code or using gtkparasite ?

Comment: There's no documentation and related to that there's no stability guarantee either AFAIK, so the class or even the whole widget could disappear in the next version (it's not likely but just pointing that out).

Comment: The whole widget wouldn't disappear, it would just be deprecated. Deprecated stuff is then removed once a new major version is out (like what happened with the GTK 2 → GTK 3 transition).

Comment: I was referring to the close-button: The way it is implemented is an internal detail of GtkHeaderBar. There's no guarantee that it is an actual GtkButton.

Answer (score 5):

**2020-10-14 EDIT:**

gtkparasite has been integrated into GTK under the name [GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector)  since GTK 3.14.

**Original answer:**

You may use [gtkparasite](https://github.com/chipx86/gtkparasite) to find the type and name of the element and how it's nested.

Answer (score 4):

the min/max/close button selectors:

```
headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton.close
headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton.maximize
headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton.minimize
```

the selector for any/each of the individual min/max/close buttons:

```
headerbar.titlebar > :last-child button.titlebutton
```

the selector for the container of the entire group of min/max/close buttons:

```
headerbar.titlebar > :last-child
```

the selector for the left-most button (usually, but not always, the application button):

```
headerbar.titlebar > :first-child > button.titlebutton
```

the selector for the left-most button's container:

```
headerbar.titlebar > :first-child
```

i used these selectors in a theme of my own, you can inspect the relevant piece(s) of code here: http://xfce-evolution.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

for python

```
header = Gtk.HeaderBar()
header.set_show_close_button(False)

button = Gtk.Button()
button.set_relief(Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
img = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("window-close-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.MENU)
button.set_image(img)
button.connect("clicked", Gtk.main_quit)
header.pack_end(button)

seperator = Gtk.Separator.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
header.pack_end(seperator)

#window/self.set_titlebar(header)
```